# Comparing two parameters in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In Objective-C I want to compare a plist to a result from an API that I am using. I am using an API that returns ingredients for recipes. I am putting these results into a table view that shows the user the recipe name and recipe ingredients. When the user selects whatever recipe they select I want to have a UIAlert appear that tells the user weather or not they have all the ingredients for that particular recipe. The ingredients from the API would be compared to the Plist. Hopefully this is clear enough, if not just ask and I will try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Gonna have trouble doing that in Xcode.  Might be able to in Objective-C, though.

Comment: BTW, did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, the ingredients the user has in his fridge are extracted from a plist file.

It's really easy to read a plist and store it in a NSDictionary. Then you can compare with the ingredients returned by your program.

If the plist is generated by your program, then you can compare whatever make sense for you in your program : index of an object "Ingredient" for example. 
If not, then your comparison might be weak, depending on what you choose to compare.

For each ingredient you have in your recipe, you can then check the number of this same ingredient that belongs to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if all of the requiredIngredients are in the cupboard. You just require a YES or a NO result. So you make two NSArrays from your data - requiredIngredients and foodCupboard.

```
- (BOOL) weHaveIngredients:(NSArray*)requiredIngredients inCupboard:(NSArray*)foodCupboard
{
 BOOL result = YES;
  For (id ingredient in requiredIngredients) {
      if !(foodCupboard containsObject:ingredient) {
         result = NO;
         break;
       }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This is better done with NSSets (collections of unique objects). You can create an NSSet from an NSArray easily:

```
NSSet* set = [NSSet setWithArray:(NSArray*)array];
```

Then you can do:

```
- (BOOL) weHaveIngredients:(NSSet*)requiredIngredients inCupboard:(NSSet*)foodCupboard
{
  BOOL result = YES;
  if (!requiredIngredients isSubsetOfSet:foodCupboard)
       result = NO;
  return result;
}
```

You could use it something like

```
NSString* alertmessage = "Sorry we can't make a cake, not enough ingredients"
if ([self weHaveIngredients:recipeIngredients inCupboard:foodCupboard])
    alertmessage = "Start baking"

UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Ingredients checked"
                         message: alertMessage
                         delegate: self
                         cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Your other issue is getting your data into the form of two arrays. You must already be getting an array out of your API as you are putting it into a tableView. I would likewise assume you know how to get a array from your (stored?) plist as you must have made the plist somehow. If you have specific data conversion issues I suggest you ask a much more specific question.

None of this addresses the question whether you have *enough* of each ingredient - to do this properly you are going to want a database of some sort.